# ExtJS Form load

Tags: extjs

Which event fires after form load? My requirement is at the time of view load based on some condation some controls set to disable mode(read only)
so how to handle this (which event)
i have try this `formpanel.on({ actioncomplete: function (form, action) {}` but ist not fired

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I just struggled with this today. The important thing to keep in mind is that there is **no event** fired on `form.loadRecord()` as it is simply a `setValues()` wrapper. If you want an event to be fired on `loadRecord()`, you will need to define it yourself by extending `Ext.form.Basic` (and potentially adding the event to relayEvents in `Ext.form.Panel`).

Answer (score 4):

I assume you a event after a record/data has loaded into the form. The action get handled in the `basicForm` and calls. Within the `basicForm` the `load()` calls `doAction()` so you should be able to use the following events from the `basicForm`

> actioncomplete : ( Form this, Action
>   action ) Fires when an action is
>   completed.
>
> actionfailed : ( Form this, Action
>   action ) Fires when an action fails.
>
> beforeaction : ( Form this, Action
>   action ) Fires before any action is
>   performed. Return false to cancel the
>   action.

Comment: Thanks for your replay,i have tried beforeaction but its not fired,and also i have tried this "Ext.getCmp("PeopleSearchFormPanel").getForm().on({ beforeaction: function (a, o) { debugger; Ext.getCmp('btaAdd').disable(); } });",,but its not fired

Comment: @MNR There must be something wrong in your code... `load()` internal calls `doAction()` and that trigger the `beforeaction` event...

Answer (score 0):

You can observe the events on an Observable using Ext.util.Observable.capture. Here is an example of observing a form, which is loaded and then submitted:

http://jsfiddle.net/el_chief/HBah5/4/

I saw these events:

fieldvaliditychange
fielderrorchange
validitychange
dirtychange
beforeaction  (i hit submit)
afterlayout
actionfailed (it did not submit to anywhere)

Don't forget, BasicForm has its own events (though I believe they are all relayed to Form), as do Fields inside a form.

Changing basic.trackResetOnLoad changes some of the events too, in particular "dirtychange"